# datetime.datatime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") adds 00:00:00 for different dates

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, strptime

When I try to convert a string into a datetime I get different results for different dates. Does anyone know the reason?

Code:

```py
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-11-29", "%Y-%m-%d")
# output: 2021-11-29

y = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-12-06", "%Y-%m-%d")
# output: 2021-12-06 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not dependent on the input date** (string). If you're using the [datetime class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) (this is what `strptime` returns here), you'll always have hours, minutes, seconds etc. - they just default to zero in case you parse a date. If you specifically want to work with dates, use the [date class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects). Ex:

```py
import datetime
# dt is instance of class datetime:
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-11-29", "%Y-%m-%d")
# we can obtain an instance of class date:
d = dt.date()
```

Now you have

```py
>>> print(dt)
2021-11-29 00:00:00 # string representation...
>>> print(d)
2021-11-29

# let's check some attributes...
>>> print(dt.microsecond) # microseconds specified but default to 0
0
>>> print(d.microsecond) # dates do not have microseconds...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'microsecond'
```